# How to quickly get complete list of citations to all my papers?

Tags: publications, citations

I need to get citations (with complete info including authors, journal, date) to all my papers.  What's the best way (hopefully without too much manual copy & paste) to do this?

What i so far tried:

Google Scholar seem to give more complete list of papers that cite my paper that it includes papers in non-English language journals etc.  But i can't see how to get authors, journal title, volume number etc quickly from the Google Scholar search output.

Comment: I haven't used it, but this might help: https://github.com/tonybreyal/Blog-Reference-Functions/blob/master/R/googleScholarXScraper/googleScholarXScraper.R

Comment: If you are using Google Scholar, you'll have to filter out lots of false positives and edit the reference files for wrong fields (e.g., wrong journal names). Google itself hasn't managed to do it properly yet, so if you know a way to automate this you might want to contact them with an offer. :)

Comment: @DaveClarke I'm sorry, it seems that I misunderstood the question. I'm not a native speaker and it sounded like "citations to [include in]" instead of "citations [pointing] to"  (/"citations of"). I deleted my previous comment.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Scopus](http://www.scopus.com) to do that, but only if you / your institute has access.

Search for an article that you (or someone else) has authored, click on the author name, then click on "citations".

[image: Scopus screenshot]

<sup>Scopus screenshot, author page</sup>

If you click on the *13* link, you will see a full list of documents citing Gerrit Holl:

[image: Scopus screenshot]

<sup>Scopus screenshot, author citation page</sup>

In my experience, Scopus doesn't have many false positives, although it might miss publications in new or unknown journals.

I'm not sure if Scopus deeplinking works, but [try this](http://www.scopus.com/authid/detail.url?origin=resultslist&authorId=31267510200&zone=) for a direct link.

Comment: _but only if you / your institute has access_ — **and** you only care about citations in venues that Scopus indexes.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to scopus, you can use Web of Science. It's also subscription based though, and your institution may or may not have access.

Go to http://apps.webofknowledge.com , select the tab labelled "Web of Science", and enter your name in the search field for the author. When the results show up, you should see a link labelled "Create citation report" near the top right corner of the results list. Follow that, and in the results table you will see an element "Citing Articles[?] :   nnn", where nnn is the number of citing articles. Click on the number, and you are taken to a list of all citing articles from the Web of Science database.

In case the result list after searching for your name has false positives, you can exclude them from the citation report either by setting a year range, or manually excluding them one-by-one.

Answer (score 4):

[Harzing's Publish or Perish](http://www.harzing.com/pop.htm) software is the tool which will probably help you most. It is a Windows application, which allows you to specify queries and then goes to Google Scholar to retrieve and sort the references, citations, etc. Besides computing h-index and a host of other bibliometric indices, it allows you to produce reports from your searches and this is what you seem to be after. Even though running only on Windows, installing [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) emulator to run it is worth the hassle.